# Using different two ado.net entity models in a one view at MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can i use two different ado.net entity in one view at MVC3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a model that encapsulates both entities.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public AdoEntityA { get; set; }        
    public AdoEntityB { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a view model that only holds the specific fields you need from the two entities.

Automapper is very useful mapping between domain entities and view models.